# Pinch Zoom in webview [Android]

Tags: javascript, android, zooming, pinch

On my website, which is loaded in the webview, there is a map. There are also java scripts that detects double tap for zoom, dragging etc. But is it possible to have a javascript that detects the use of pinch zoom ? there are several examples of it working on an iphone, and on my website there is a script for the pinch zoom but it is only working on iphone.....

Is it possible to get it to work on Android ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open-source library called [android-pinch](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/) that you can include in your project to enable pinch zoom if you switch your `WebView` to a `WebImageView`. Here's an example of usage...

```
// create the WebImageView object from xml
WebImageView img = (WebImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_pic);
// fetches the image in a background thread
img.setImageFromURL("http://www.mysite.com/mypicture.jpg");
// enable pinch-zoom abilities on the image
new PinchImageView(img);
```

Comment: I think he's trying to detect the pinch from within the JS of the web page.

Comment: I tried importing this jar file and executed my code, but I am getting an ClassNotFound Exception during runtime. Any help?

Answer (score 11):

When you would like to scale web content in you WebView and enable pinch and zoom, I prefer the simple android way.

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and you can even hide the controls if you are using API 11 or higher

```
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly in a webview, but in any layout, that I wrote a piece of code for detecting pinch in an Android view.

It took me days to find out a solution for this, so I made my own custom pinch gesture detector.

You can see it in Github: http://github.com/luisfer/Neckar

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This excellent [tutorial](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847?tag=rbxccnbzd1) shows how to implement the Pinch gesture.